# Sub-struct with some values filled in

Tags: racket

Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
(struct house (bedrooms bathrooms address price))
```

How can I create a sub-struct for, say, houses with 3 bedrooms and 2 bathrooms?

```
(struct 3-2-house house
   ; ???
   ; somehow fill in bedrooms=3 and bathrooms=2
   ; ???
)

(define house-on-apple-street (3-2-house "123 apple street" 100000))
```

It seems something like `#:auto` is called for here but it's not clear how to apply `#:auto` to fields inherited from parent struct ...

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot create a sub-struct to do this. However, you can define a new function to act as a "constructor". Would that be good enough for you? Why is it important that it's a sub-struct and not just a new constructor function?